# Calculate mean of elements in array with same "identifier"

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have a numpy array of the following form:

```
['viola.jpg' '0.81' '1.0693461723' '100']
['viola.jpg' '0.44' '1.31469086921' '18']
['viola.jpg' '0.8' '3.92096084523' '73']
['vlasta.jpg' '0.88' '1.36559123399' '110']
['vlasta.jpg' '0.88' '1.88126493001' '45']
['vlasta.jpg' '0.76' '1.0510328514' '88']
```

I want to average for every new identifier in column 0 the values in column 1 and 2. From the above I would like to get something like:

```
['viola.jpg' '0.68' '2.14354']
['vlasta.jpg' '0.84' '1.41324']
```

(the last column is completely irrelevant here, it can be a mean of the numbers, a random one of them, or completely left out)

I have tried to do this - but it fails because reduceat doesn't like flexible types (my array of the above form being "pics")

```
pics = pics[pics[:,0].argsort()]
print pics
last = pics[:,0]
w = np.where(last[:-1] != last[1:])[0] + 1
w = np.concatenate(([0], w, [len(pics)])) #add 0 and last value
print type(pics), type(w)
means = np.add.reduceat(pics, w[:-1])/np.diff(w)[:,None]
```

Comment: Are those lists? And are those actual strings instead of numbers? Also, **what have you tried so far?**

Comment: *values may not be correct in my example*? It'd be nice if indeed you did know what values to expect. Also - what attempts have you made at researching solutions to this - what specifically are you stuck on etc...?

Comment: ye olde itertools.groupby and probably a nested list comprehension will get you far

Comment: If you use a dictionary, it would be MUCH easier.

Comment: @JonClements I just meant I calculated the means for my desired "output array" in my head.

Comment: @RikPoggi I have tried this http://paste2.org/p/3168923 fails on account that reduceat doesn't like flexible types

Comment: Well - to try and improve this question before it's closed - you need to answer 1) Do you have a list of lists - at the moment, you have several separate lists of a single string (you're missing the `,` delimiter) - 2) Instead of calculating it in your head - verify your expected output with your input (use a calculator - you do have a computer with a calculator tool even if you don't have a calculator on your desk right?) 3) Show any attempt you've made so far, or at least resources you've found that you don't fully understand

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND could you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: @TheChymera Just seen your post with the code - great - so the other thing is - now you've effectively introduced you would like a `numpy` solution - so add that tag to your question, and take your code out of the pastebin and [edit] your question to include it ;)

Comment: @TheChymera Good job - I've removed my downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where you got this list of strings from, but if it is from a file, use `genfromtxt` to get a nice numpy array from it, with the correct types:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO   # to create example file
s = """ viola.jpg  0.81 1.0693461723  100
        viola.jpg  0.44 1.31469086921  18
        viola.jpg  0.8  3.92096084523  73
        vlasta.jpg 0.88 1.36559123399 110
        vlasta.jpg 0.88 1.88126493001  45
        vlasta.jpg 0.76 1.0510328514   88"""
f = StringIO(s) # creates example file with content above
a = np.genfromtxt(f, names = "image, someval, another, someid", dtype=['S12', float, float, int])
```

Now, `a` is a structured array.  You can access the columns using the `field` name:

```
images = np.uniques(a['image']) # gets unique values of the column named 'image'
b = np.empty(len(images), dtype = a.dtype)
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    m = a['image'] == image
    b[i] = (image,) + tuple(a[m][n].mean() for n in a.dtype.names[1:])
```

:( Maybe it's not that much better... sorry for the exaggeration.  However, it's worth it to introduce you to structured arrays.  Now, to look at `b`:

```
In [3]: b
Out[3]: 
array([('viola.jpg', 0.6833333333333332, 2.101665962246667, 63),
       ('vlasta.jpg', 0.84, 1.4326296718, 81)], 
      dtype=[('image', '|S12'), ('someval', '<f8'), ('another', '<f8'), ('someid', '<i8')])

In [4]: b['image']
Out[4]: 
array(['viola.jpg', 'vlasta.jpg'], 
      dtype='|S12')

In [5]: b['someval']
Out[5]: array([ 0.68333333,  0.84      ])

In [6]: b[1]
Out[6]: ('vlasta.jpg', 0.84, 1.4326296718, 81)

In [7]: b[b['image']=='viola.jpg']
Out[7]: 
array([('viola.jpg', 0.6833333333333332, 2.101665962246667, 63)], 
      dtype=[('image', '|S12'), ('someval', '<f8'), ('another', '<f8'), ('someid', '<i8')])
```

Given what you are starting with in the question, you can do something like this:

```
a = np.array([['viola.jpg', '0.81', '1.0693461723', '100'],
              ['viola.jpg', '0.44', '1.3146908692', '18'],
              ['viola.jpg', '0.8', '3.9209608452', '73'],
              ['vlasta.jpg', '0.88', '1.3655912339', '110'],
              ['vlasta.jpg', '0.88', '1.8812649300', '45'],
              ['vlasta.jpg', '0.76', '1.0510328514', '88']])

uniques = np.uniques(a[:,0])
b = np.empty((len(uniques), len(a[0])), dtype = 'S12')

for i,s in enumerate(uniques):
    m = a[:,0] == s
    b[i] = [s] + [a[m,j].astype(float).mean() for j in [1,2]] + [int(a[m,3].astype(float).mean())]
print b
#[['viola.jpg' '0.6833333333' '2.1016659622' '64']
# ['vlasta.jpg' '0.84' '1.4326296717' '81']]
```

If you use a better data structure it's MUCH easier to keep track of what's a `float`, `int`, and `string`.  For proof, see @HYRY's answer.

Comment: what do you mean by a batter data structure?

Comment: I'll edit to show a *structured* array

Comment: I read my file with http://paste2.org/p/3169593 and genfromtxt won't work because AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' :(

Comment: @askewchan You can _numpify_ your answer quite a bit: `uniques, _ = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_inverse=True); counts = np.bincount(_); mean_1 = np.bincount(_, weights=a[:, 1]) / counts; mean_2 = np.bincount(_, weights=a[:, 2]) / counts`.

Comment: @TheChymera What `list` were you trying to `split` with `genfromtxt`?  You can give it a delimiter kwarg as well: `a = np.genfromtxt(dataFile, delimiter = ',', names=..., dtype=...)`

Comment: @Jaime Thanks --- I couldn't easily incorporate your comment but at least I fixed it to use `np.uniques` instead of `set`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas to do this quickly:

```
import pandas as pd

data=[['viola.jpg', '0.81', '1.0693461723', '100'],
['viola.jpg', '0.44', '1.31469086921', '18'],
['viola.jpg', '0.8', '3.92096084523', '73'],
['vlasta.jpg', '0.88', '1.36559123399', '110'],
['vlasta.jpg', '0.88', '1.88126493001', '45'],
['vlasta.jpg', '0.76', '1.0510328514', '88']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=float)
print df.groupby(0).mean()
```

Result:

```
                   1         2          3
0                                        
viola.jpg   0.683333  2.101666  63.666667
vlasta.jpg  0.840000  1.432630  81.000000
```

Comment: OP might want strings of floats and ints as the example output shows... not sure.

Comment: no, I don't want strings specifically. pandas sounds wonderful, but I would not require the entire module just for this one function. Many thanks, though.